# Monomial Characters of Quotient Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

The following statement provides (if true) a powerful tool for inductive proofs. Can anyone confirm if it is true:

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Is it true that if $\chi\in Irr(G/N)$ is a monomial character of $G/N$ of degree $\chi(1)$, then $G$ has a monomial character of same degree?

Comment: Can't we just take the inflation of $\chi$ to $G$? It is still monomial, because inflation commutes with induction. I.e.: if $\chi = \phi\!\uparrow_{K/N}^{G/N}$ is an irreducible monomial character, then $(\mathrm{Inf}^K \phi) \!\uparrow_K^G = \mathrm{Inf}^G (\phi\!\uparrow_{K/N}^{G/N}) = \mathrm{Inf}^G \chi$ is an irreducible monomial character of $G$.

Comment: Ah yes, I think actually this suffices!